# Click Listener for Info Window Google Maps V2

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a simple "Place" class:

```
public class Plac{
    String name;
    int id;
    LatLng latlng;

    public Product(String name, int id, LatLng latlng) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id= id;
        this.latlng = latlng;
    }
}
```

and I'm adding "Places" to an ArrayList like this: (**Note** the names are **not** unique)

```
ArrayList<Place> places = new ArrayList<Place>();
places.add(new Place("McDonald's", 1));
places.add(new Place("McDonald's", 2));
places.add(new Place("McDonald's", 3));
```

I'm adding markers to my Google Map like this:

```
for(Place place : places)
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place.latlng).title(place.name);
```

I want to know how to add a listener for each marker that is being added to the map. I've tried to use

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

        }
    });
```

which works, however, the only thing I can do with this is get the title of the marker which is not unique so I can't really find which EXACT "Place" object is being clicked on. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could just use the `LatLng` object returned from calling `getPosition()` on the `Marker` to uniquely identify each `Marker`, and find the match in your `places` array.

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

            LatLng latLon = marker.getPosition();

            //Cycle through places array
            for(Place place : places){
               if (latLon.equals(place.latlng)){
                    //match found!  Do something....
               }

            }
        }
    });
```

Documentation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html

Comment: @user1282637 Sure, no problem!  You could also add a unique `snippet` to each `Marker`, and use that.

Comment: That's true, I could just put the Place.id into snippet...thanks for the help

Comment: I used your LatLng solution. It was the simplest to implement. This obviously wouldn't work with two places that have the same address (i.e. shops at a mall) but I don't have that issues for my app. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

I have a method to get the index of the marker and you can use it to get the element in Places.

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            Log.i("MAP", "the index of this element is: " + String.valueOf(getMarkerIndex(marker.getId())));
        }
    });
```

getMarkerIndex() method:

```
private int getMarkerIndex(String index){
    int myIndex = -1;
    try{
        myIndex = Integer.parseInt(index.replace("m", ""));
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        Log.e(TAG, nfe.getMessage());
    }
    return myIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

edit your loop this way

```
for(Place place : places) {
    Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place.latlng).title(place.name);
    place.markerId = marker.getId();
}
```

Of course you need add variable markerid to `place`

getId();

```
Gets this marker's id. The id will be unique amongst all Markers on a map.
```

then in `onInfoWindowClickListener` you can find place by markerId.

Comment: Sweeeet this looks like my best bet. Will update when I test it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i use the key of an object to find it 
  for example i have two places:

> place1 : name= "test" , address ="test2" , id= 0
>   place2 : name=  "test" , address ="test2" , id= 1

in the marker they appear the same if i use this :

```
 map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng)
                            .title(name).snippet(address);
```

so to distinguish between them i modified the code to be :

```
  map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng)
                            .title(id+"-"name).snippet(address);
```

and in the infoWindowClickListener i just access the id by

```
  String  id=marker.getTitle().substring(0,1);//if your places are < 10
```

### 2nd way

is ceating your custom infoWindow 
and create your object "place"
http://androidfreakers.blogspot.com/2013/08/display-custom-info-window-with.html

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a `HashMap`.

```
private HashMap<Marker, Place> markerMap = new HashMap<Marker, Place>();
```

In your loop:

```
for(Place place : places){
   MarkerOption marker =new MarkerOptions().position(place.latlng).title(place.name);
   map.addMarker(marker);
   markerMap.put(marker, place)
}
```

In your Listener:

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
           Place place = markerMap.get(marker);// here you get your exact Place Object
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is not optimal. HashMap occupy memory and are a bit slow.

Comment: @RediOne1 in this case, i think it's more optimal than looping all places each time the use click a marker.