# Android Google maps adding multiple markers, cannot bind onInfoWindowClick method

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am currently trying to add multiple markers to my Android application. This works just perfectly. The only thing I am getting stuck at is the fact that I cannot bind multiple "onInfoWindowClick" on multiple markers.

For instance, if I have like:

```
                for (int i = 0; i < randomList; i++) {

                        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(MainActivity.list.get(i).aMessage);

                            // adding marker
                            googleMap.addMarker(marker);



                        googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                                // Do something onclick
                            }
                        });

                }
```

This would result in a infowindowclick that works, for each marker, but I always get the same data back inside that "// Do something onclick", this is because the last marker is getting set to this event.

What is my procedure to attach this event to multiple markers?

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `Marker` on every loop and execute the method: `showInfoWindow()`;

```
 for (int i = 0; i < randomList; i++) {

                      //  MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(MainActivity.list.get(i).aMessage);   
                     // adding marker
                     //    googleMap.addMarker(marker);    
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(MainActivity.list.get(i).aMessage)).showInfoWindow();



                        googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                                // Do something onclick
                            }
                        });

                }
```

by the way you are setting the same `latlng` value!

Answer (score 0):

You should not be calling `setOnInfoWindowClickListener()` inside a loop, this just needs to be called once, and it will apply to all Markers.

The Marker object that gets passed into `onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)` will always be the Marker that was just clicked.

So, take that out of the loop.  Next, in order to figure out what Marker was just clicked, you could get the title of the Marker, and loop through your list until you find the list item that has a `aMessage` value that corresponds to the Marker's title.

Note you could also identify that current marker by location by calling `marker.getPosition();`.

```
       googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                //get location of Marker that was just clicked
                LatLng latLon = marker.getPosition();

                // get the title of Marker that was just clicked
                String title = marker.getTitle();

                //find item in the list that corresponds to currently clicked Marker
                for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.this.list.size(); i++){
                    if (title.equals(MainActivity.this.list.get(i).aMessage)){
                        //found current list item corresponding to
                        //the Marker that was just clicked!
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < randomList; i++) {

            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(MainActivity.this.list.get(i).aMessage);
            // adding marker
            googleMap.addMarker(marker);

        }
```

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976663/click-listener-for-info-window-google-maps-v2/29977102#29977102), you may find that helpful as well.