# Maps API only loads with location setting GPS

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I use the Google Maps API in my Android app and locate the user with 
`LocationManager` and `getLongitude()`, `getLatitude()`.
But now there have to be strange settings on the mobile phone to get a map. The location setting has to be changed to only use GPS, and even then it's not working all the time, sometimes the map is not loaded. If not loaded the app shuts down at the point the first marker is set because of `NullPointerException`.

Why is this and how can I prevent it?
I already tried with `getMapAsync` but it didn't help.

```
GoogleMap googleMap;
LocationManager locationManager;
String provider;
Criteria criteria;
Location myLocation;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

   try {
        if(googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
        iconDone = R.drawable.markerdone;
        icon = R.drawable.marker;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Marker marker1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(49.793012, 9.926201))
            .title(getString(R.string.Title1))
            .snippet("")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icon)));
```

Comment: Show your code to give a better understanding of why your issue is happening.  Are you using FusedLocationProvider?

Comment: it doesn't load when you first open the app? or after going to another activity/fragment? and it doesn't load and crash (If so post your logcat)! or it does load with out any content ? clarify your question please.
help us to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `getLastKnownLocation()`, which will frequently return a null Location, since it doesn't explicitly request a new location lock.

So, when your app is crashing, it's due to a NullPointerException when trying to de-reference the Location object.

It's best to request location updates, and if you only need one, just un-register for location updates once the first `onLocationChanged()` callback comes in.

Here is an example using the FusedLocationProvider API, which automatically uses Network Location as well as GPS Location if needed:

Relevant imports for the Activity:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
        implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {


    GoogleMap googleMap;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Marker marker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Toast.makeText(this,"buildGoogleApiClient", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        googleMap = map;

        setUpMap();

    }

    public void setUpMap() {

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        //mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F);

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        //unregister location updates
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);

        //remove previously placed Marker
        if (marker != null) {
            marker.remove();
        }

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        //place marker where user just clicked
        marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("Current Location")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA)));

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(latLng).zoom(5).build();

        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

}
```

build.gradle (change to whatever version of Google Play Services you are currently using):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

SupportMapFragment in the layout xml (you can use a MapFragment as well):

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Using only Network Location:

[image]

The Map moves to the current location seconds after launch:

[image]

Comment: I did everything like you but on the onLocationChanged method it gives me an error saying "method does not override method from its superclass"

Comment: Where would you set up `setOnInfoClickListener` if I use the current location in it to know it the user is near the marker?

Comment: @maidi I just updated the formatting so you can see all of the interfaces that the Activity implements without scrolling, take a look!  Also make sure to import the correct LocationListener: `import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;`

Comment: @maidi for `setOnInfoWindowClickListener` see this answer, set it up in `setUpMap()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976663/click-listener-for-info-window-google-maps-v2/29977102#29977102

Comment: I set up the current position like you in `onLocationChanged()` and named it `myposition`.
Now I want to use it in `onWindowClickListener` and set up a Location variable with `setLatitude(myposition.latitude)` and longitude the same way. With this `Location` variable I use `distanceTo`. (This is the way I did before I added your solution). Is it the wrong way to do it?

Comment: @maidi that sounds right! If you can't get it working ask a new question and ping me in a comment and I'll take a look!